Migrate stored procedure from Firebird to Oracle
I have some stored procedures in Firebird that I need to migrate to a new database in Oracle. Here's a simplified example of one of them:
create or alter procedure CALCULA_ARTIC (
    FECHA_INICIO date,
    FECHA_FIN date)
returns (
    COSTE varchar(100),
    PROVEEDOR varchar(100),
    IDARTICULO integer)
as
begin
  for select CS.COSTE, P.PROVEEDOR,
             AA.IDARTICULO
      from ALBARAN A
          join COSTE_SUBGRUPO CS on CS.IDCOSTESUBGRUPO = A.IDCOSTESUBGRUPO
          join PROVEEDOR P on P.IDPROVEEDOR = A.IDPROVEEDOR
      where ALB.FECHA between :FECHA_INICIO and :FECHA_FIN
      into :COSTE, :PROVEEDOR, :IDARTICULO
  do
  begin
    suspend;
  end
end

To call this procedure in Firebird, I would just do
Select * from CALCULAR_ARTIC(:FECHA_INICIO, :FECHA_FIN)

How can I achieve the same behaviour in Oracle?
I've tried using functions that would return me a refcursor, but then I have trouble using a select over that cursor, because I don't want to print them using dbms_output, I need the values to be return in a table format such as:
COSTE  PROVEEDOR  IDARTICULO
-----  ---------  ----------
13     1          125
7,5    2          89


Oracle Pipelined Function is very similar to Firebird selectable Stored Procedures. Example in the link is exactly what you ask for.

This is one option, which uses custom-declared types and a function. In this example, I'm passing department number and returning list of employees (their number, name and salary).
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_row IS OBJECT (empno NUMBER, ename VARCHAR2 (10), sal NUMBER);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF t_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (par_deptno IN dept.deptno%TYPE)
  2     RETURN t_tab
  3  IS
  4     retval  t_tab;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT t_row (empno, ename, sal)
  7       BULK COLLECT INTO retval
  8       FROM emp
  9      WHERE deptno = par_deptno;
 10
 11     RETURN retval;
 12  END f_test;
 13  /

Function created.

Testing:
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE (f_test (10));

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7839 KING             5000
      7934 MILLER           1300

SQL>


You said you want a procedure; you can, with an OUT parameter, but - for result you posted - I'd say that function is a better choice.

I think the SUSPEND behavior is closer to PIPE ROW, and fetching into a TABLE OF may put pressure on the memory if the number of rows is huge. It's possible to mix BULK COLLECT and PIPE ROW to get benefit of both. See Steven Feuerstein article https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall
